# error 5 invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: vba

I have used this code but this code work one system and when I am use this macrobook to other computer error maggasae found runtime  error 5 invalid procedure call or argument

Please someone provide soluction.

Thanks in advance

```
Sub ExportAPDF_and_SaveAsXLSX() 
    Dim wsThisWorkSheet As Worksheet 
    Dim strFileName As String 
    Dim strBasePath As String 

    strBasePath = "C:\Users\bmohan.CHECKMATE\Desktop\Debit Note\" 
    strFileName = Range("aa13") 
    Set wsThisWorkSheet = ActiveSheet wsThisWorkSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _ 
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _ filename:=strBasePath & strFileName, _ 
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _ 
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _ 
        OpenAfterPublish:=False 
    MsgBox "Data Exported Successfully""" 
    Range("R11").Value = Range("x11").Value + 1 
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please format your code by highlighting it and hitting Ctrl+K, not in bold please

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. 
Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named 
["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). 
And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). 
You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Is the username different on the other computer? If so, you will want to use an environment variable like this:

```
strBasePath = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\Desktop\Debit Note\"
```